# Glyphicons become corrupted if Bootstrap CSS file is hosted locally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, character-encoding, twitter-bootstrap-3, webfonts

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 on a project. There's a fixed requirement of not hosting any files externally. But when I host the `.css` and `.js` files locally, the [Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) become corrupted.

Here's what it should look like:

[image]

Using [`bootstrap.min.css` from the original CDN](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css) issues no errors, but placing the same file on the local server will affect the icons rendering, like in the image below:

[image]

It doesn't seem to matter if I download and save the original file using wget, DownThemAll, or open it on Firefox and use the "Save As" feature. It doesn't matter if the `<link>` href is `href="/css/bootstrap.min.css`, `href="http://www.domain.com/css/bootstrap.min.css` or `href="http://www.domain.com/bootstrap.min.css`.

My dev machine is running Linux. I can only use it to browse the site, both on my dev machine and in production. I'm using Firefox 26, [but changing the value of `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19409615/798677) has no effect. As far as I can tell, the only difference that causes the render error is the CSS file location.

The issue happens both on my dev machine and in the live server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glyphicons are webfonts loaded from addresses hardcoded in the CDN version of Twitter Bootstrap. The original code is:

> @font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg')}

You have to either edit the CSS or place the font files on the `/fonts/` folder. You can obtain both the fonts and the CSS files at the "[customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)" page.

Comment: I hate it when I bang my head looking for a solution, then ask it on SE, then find it myself.

Comment: Thanks alot. this helped me.