# Bootstrap3 glyphicon calendar not displaying correctly in firefox

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having all sorts of issues getting one glyphicon working on firefox from a meteor application (not sure that's relevant).

The calendar icon works fine on chrome (now that i've updated bootstrap to 3.1.1) but on firefox it continues to just show a + icon.

The code generating the icon is

```
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
```

I tried the suggested change in 
[Boootstrap glyphicons Firefox issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085942/boootstrap-glyphicons-firefox-issues)
but no joy unfortunately.

Any other suggestions out there?

Comment: This is supposed to work. When you've updated Bootstrap to 3.1.1, have you updated your font files ?

Comment: Yep. Pulled in the lot.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds similar to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10106 , but that was fixed in Bootstrap v3.0.1. Triple-check that all your Glyphicons font files and your Less/CSS files are up-to-date. (Maybe your browser's cache also needs purging?)

Is it only that one particular icon that doesn't render? What OS are you using?

Comment: I have no idea why, but the icons are now working on both browsers. I've been hacking on something else for a couple of days, updated meteor no the new version (and packages) and its now good. Go figure.

Comment: The same here. But only the calendar was changed to + icon. I'll try an update later and tell if it worked.